# We have no visitors :(

Tags: bug, status-norepro

[image]

We have zero visitors/day.

Area51 gets it right, though:

[image]

Comment: It shows as 1,392 for me now.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Hmm, yes, *now* it's working.

Comment: Sounds like [a caching issue](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/). I'm going to mark this as status-norep for now. If it happens again, ping me.